# iOS (objective-c) compression_decode_buffer() returns zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, compression

I'm converting a very large json result on my server to a compressed format that I can decompress on my objective c app.  I would prefer to use the [iOS 9 compression lib](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression/1481000-compression_decode_buffer?language=objc) if possible (libcompression.tbd), described in [Apple's CompressionSample/BlockCompression.c sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CompressionSample/Listings/CompressionSample_BlockCompression_c.html).

I'm passing the compressed NSData result to the following method:

```
#include "compression.h"
```

...

```
    - (NSData *) getDecompressedData:(NSData *) compressed {
        size_t dst_buffer_size = 20000000;   //20MB
        uint8_t *dst_buffer = malloc(dst_buffer_size);
        uint8_t *src_buffer = malloc(compressed.length);
        [compressed getBytes:src_buffer length:compressed.length];

        size_t decompressedSize = compression_decode_buffer(dst_buffer, dst_buffer_size, src_buffer, compressed.length, nil, COMPRESSION_ZLIB);
        NSData *decompressed = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:dst_buffer length:decompressedSize];
        return decompressed;
    }
```

The `compressed` parameter has a length that matches my server logs, but the result from `compression_decode_buffer` is always zero and `dst_buffer` is not modified.  I'm not receiving any errors, and the log has no relevant info.

I've tried ZLIB and LZ4 compression / decompression methods and several libraries on the server side, all with the same result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much testing and research, I found that the compression library I was using on my server adds a compression header (1st two bytes), per [RFC1950](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt).  I skipped those two bytes and `compression_decode_buffer` works like a champ!

```
- (NSData *) getDecompressedData:(NSData *) compressed {
    size_t dst_buffer_size = 20000000;   //20MB
    uint8_t *dst_buffer = malloc(dst_buffer_size);
    uint8_t *src_buffer = malloc(compressed.length);
    [compressed getBytes:src_buffer range:NSMakeRange(2, compressed.length - 2)];

    size_t decompressedSize = compression_decode_buffer(dst_buffer, dst_buffer_size, src_buffer, compressed.length - 2, nil, COMPRESSION_ZLIB);
    NSData *decompressed = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:dst_buffer length:decompressedSize];
    return decompressed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much, azcoastal - saved me heaps of time!

Here's some working Swift code ..

```
let bytes = [UInt8](data)      // Data -> [Uint8]
// Need to remove the first 2 bytes (a header) from the array!!
let slice = bytes[2...bytes.count-1]
let noheader = Array(slice)

let dst_count = bytes.count * MULTIPLY
var dst = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: dst_count)  // destination
let size = compression_decode_buffer(&dst, dst_count,
        noheader, noheader.count, nil, COMPRESSION_ZLIB)
```